# Trying to return a new string with some characters being replaced with other characters

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am learning TypeScript and for this particular problem, I am trying to replace certain characters in a string with another character. So if there is an A, I want to replace it with a T. If there is a T, I want to replace it with an A. If there is a C, I want to replace it with a G. If there is a G, I want to replace it with a C.

I was given the following initial code to work with:

```
  export class Kata {
      static dnaStrand(dna: string) {
        //your code here
      }
    }
```

The outputs should be like this:

```
dnaStrand("ATTGC") // return "TAACG"
    
dnaStrand("GTAT") // return "CATA"
```

So my initial thought was to use a for loop to iterate over the string and return a new string, where the characters I mentioned above would be replaced with other characters (also mentioned above). When I run the code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silosc/jd73ovg0/9/), I get the following error message: `Unexpected token 'export'`.  Can someone help me out?  I figured that if I wanted to return a new string, I would have to loop over the string and replace the characters by chaining the  replace methods together.  Was this the best approach?

```
export class Kata {
  static dnaStrand(dna: string) {
    for (let i = 0; i < dna.length; i++){
        dna = dna.replace('A','T').replace('T', 'A').replace('C', 'G').replace('G', 'C');
    }
    return dna;
  }
}

Kata.dnaStrand("ATTGC");
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `export`?

Comment: @iota That's how the question was given to me.  Should it not go there?

Comment: The export issue will depend on your environment. The version of typescript is probably an older version which doesn't yet support the new export syntax. For testing purposes, you should be fine to just remove where it says export, but don't forget to put it back in if you need to submit your work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach for replacing the characters won't actually work at the moment.

The way that the replace function works is like this:

replace(strMatch, strReplace) will create a new string from your old string with all of the instances of `strMatch` replaced by `strReplace` and return it. (More information at this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

What you have at the moment won't work correctly in your instance for 2 reasons

1. Having the replace function being called in a for loop means the replacement will be done on the input string `dna.length` times. You would actually only want this to be done once
2. Chaining multiple replaces like that is counter productive. Looking at the first 2 replace calls: The first one replaces all your instances of `A` with `T`, leaving you with `TTTGC`. The second one then replaces all your instances of `T` with `A`, leaving you with `AAAGC` and so on. Notice how each chaining of the replace function is being called on a new string, not your original one.

One way you could go about getting this task done would be to loop over the array string (as you already are), but instead of calling the replace function, you just want to append to a string the value for the corresponding replacement of dna[i].

I would probably end up doing something like this (but there are all sorts of ways you could get it done! This is definitely not the best solution)

```
static dnaStrand(dna: string): string {
  let newDna: string = '';
  const map: Record<string, string> = {'A': 'T', 'T': 'A', 'G': 'C', 'C': 'G'};
  for (let i = 0; i < dna.length; i++){
    newDna += map[dna[i]]; 
  }

  return newDna;
}
```